# why is this chrome.browserAction.setIcon method not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[I'm looking at the documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon) and I can't figure out whats wrong in my code:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  details.imageData = {
    "48": "Icons/iconfavorite48x.png",
    "64": "Icons/iconfavorite64x.png",
    "128": "Icons/iconfavorite128x.png"
  }
});
```

the documentaion says :

> Note that 'details.imageData = foo' is equivalent to
>   'details.imageData = {'19': foo}'

so I'm extremely confused

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your code is basically a big syntax error. A JavaScript object literal expects to be a list of pairs `key: value`. You can't (and don't need) any assignments there in the `key` part.

So, fixing **only** the syntax error, it will be:

```
// Still wrong:
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  imageData : {
    "48": "Icons/iconfavorite48x.png",
    "64": "Icons/iconfavorite64x.png",
    "128": "Icons/iconfavorite128x.png"
  }
});
```

This will fail. `imageData` expects binary blobs of pixel data obtained, for example, from `<canvas>`. If you want to supply paths, you need to use `path` property:

```
// Still wrong:
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path : {
    "48": "Icons/iconfavorite48x.png",
    "64": "Icons/iconfavorite64x.png",
    "128": "Icons/iconfavorite128x.png"
  }
});
```

Note that you can only provide sizes it expects. If you include any other, it will fail. Quoting the docs:

> If the number of image pixels that fit into one screen space unit equals scale, then image with size scale * 19 will be selected. Initially only scales 1 and 2 will be supported.

A normal-sized icon is 19x19 pixels; on high-DPI screens Chrome may show a 38x38 icon.

**Update: since Chrome has switched to Material Design in 53, this now expects 16x16 and 32x32 respectively. You can supply both old and new sizes without errors.**

So you can do this:

```
// Correct
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path : {
    "19": "Icons/iconfavorite19x.png",
    "38": "Icons/iconfavorite38x.png"
  }
});

// Also correct
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path : {
    "19": "Icons/iconfavorite19x.png"
  }
});

// Also correct
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path : "Icons/iconfavorite19x.png"
});
```

The images don't *have* to have these dimensions, they will be scaled if necessary; but it's of course better to be exact.

Comment: yup, that works, I've never used or seen a javascript object before, which is surprising

Comment: Glad to help. Thought it would be useful to untangle this step by step.

Comment: The offical docs are confusing. I was also confused by the same last year when the docs refer to a non existant "details" which then turns out to refer to the object passed.

Comment: @ZigMandel I even filed a bug regarding this part of the docs: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423556

Answer (score 9):

For **manifest version 3** you have to use `chrome.action.setIcon` instead of `chrome.browserAction.setIcon`.

For example, gray images in a separate folder:

```
   chrome.action.setIcon({
        path: {
            "16": "/icons/gray/icon16.png",
            "19": "/icons/gray/icon19.png",
            "32": "/icons/gray/icon32.png",
            "48": "/icons/gray/icon48.png",
            "128": "/icons/gray/icon128.png"
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, if not part of the question, it could be solved via setBadgeText:

`state` *is my own variable.*

```
chrome.action.setBadgeText({
  text: (state ? 'off' : '')
});

chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
  color: '#2f2f2f'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in Chrome V3

```
chrome.action.setIcon({ path: "media/background1.png" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in v3 : use `"icons"` in manifest remember icons object have key value pair where key define the size of icon and value is the path of the icon.

```
chrome.action.setIcon({
    path : {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png"
    }
});
```